# Play music in webview while app is in background

Tags: ios

I make an application connect to my website using a `UIWebVew`.  The website contains music.
When the application is open the music works, but when the app in background the music stops.
 I use this code:

```
NSString *path = @"http://localhost:8888/wordpress-1/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:req];
```

How can I make the music play while the app is in the background?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to play music while app in background?

Comment: I thought the question was quite obvious???? "How can I make the music play while the app is in the background?".

Comment: @MartinH, check edit history, thegrinner's comment was made before the edit adding the last line appeared.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your app won't run while its in the background unless you give it the audio background mode capability.

Secondly a UIWebView has to run in the foreground (unless that has changed with iOS7, I've not used it recently), in which case you can't run it in the background. So you will have to play the audio natively if that is still the case.